# How can I run a github codepoject on Mac Mavericks?

Tags: mac, osx-mavericks, xcode, github, afloat

I want to install Afloat to Mavericks, and this is the link I keep finding - https://github.com/fjolnir/afloat - but I have no idea where to even begin on this. What am I supposed to download, what program do I run it in?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I don't get the sense that you understand what's involved in compiling code on OS X, in which case you'd need to understand the basics of not just Xcode, but git.

Fortunately, someone by the name of Chris Van Patten has already documented a simpler method of installing it.  His blog post [Master your windows with Afloat for Mac](http://www.chrisvanpatten.com/master-windows-afloat-mac) describes how to install an already compiled version.

If you'd prefer to manually compile the source code from GitHub yourself, you should find a [GitHub tutorial](http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1) to learn how to properly pull down the code to your computer and then find a tutorial that suits you (Google the terms: xcode & tutorial) on compiling software with Xcode. Neither of these are trivial endeavors, but well worth learning.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site http://git-scm.com/download/mac download git. Install git. Open up terminal and go via the terminal to a empty folder you want the source code to be stored. Use the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/fjolnir/afloat.git
```

Use gcc to compile or XCODE IDE.